# Filtering pandas dataframe by date to count views for timeline of programs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I need to count viewers by program for a streaming channel from a json logfile.
I identify the programs by their starttimes, such as:

So far I have two Dataframes like this:

The first one contains all the timestamps from the logfile

```
viewers_from_log = pd.read_json('sqllog.json', encoding='UTF-8')
# Convert date string to pandas datetime object:
viewers_from_log['time'] = pd.to_datetime(viewers_from_log['time'])
```

[image]

Source JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "logid": 191605,
        "time": "0:00:17"
    },
    {
        "logid": 191607,
        "time": "0:00:26"
    },
    {
        "logid": 191611,
        "time": "0:01:20"
    }
]
```

The second contains the starting times and titles of the programs

```
programs_start_time = pd.DataFrame.from_dict('programs.json', orient='index')
```

[image]
Source JSON file:

```
{
    "2019-05-29": [
        {
            "title": "\"Amiről a kövek mesélnek\"",
            "startTime_dt": "2019-05-29T00:00:40Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "Koffer - Kedvcsináló Kul(t)túrák Külföldön",
            "startTime_dt": "2019-05-29T00:22:44Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "Gubancok",
            "startTime_dt": "2019-05-29T00:48:08Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

So what I need to do is to count the entries / program in the log file and link them to the program titles.

Comment: Seems like you could relatively easily obtain what you want using histogram, declaring (slightly preprocessed) programme's start times as bins. Could you provide at least a sample of your data? I mean in easily copied format.

Comment: I have added examples from the source JSON, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach is to slice log data for each date range from program data and get the shape. Next add column for program data with results:

```
import pandas as pd

# setup test data
log_data = {'Time': ['2019-05-30 00:00:26', '2019-05-30 00:00:50', '2019-05-30 00:05:50','2019-05-30 00:23:26']}
log_data = pd.DataFrame(data=log_data)

program_data = {'Time': ['2019-05-30 00:00:00', '2019-05-30 00:22:44'],
            'Program': ['Program 1', 'Program 2']}
program_data = pd.DataFrame(data=program_data)


counts = []
for index, row in program_data.iterrows():
    # get counts on selected range
    try:
        log_range = log_data[(log_data['Time'] > program_data.loc[index].values[0]) & (log_data['Time'] < program_data.loc[index+1].values[0])]
        counts.append(log_range.shape[0])
    except:
        log_range = log_data[log_data['Time'] > program_data.loc[index].values[0]]
        counts.append(log_range.shape[0])

 # add aditional column with collected counts
 program_data['Counts'] = counts
```

Output:

```
                  Time    Program  Counts
 0  2019-05-30 00:00:00  Program 1       3
 1  2019-05-30 00:22:44  Program 2       1
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. I actually started to go in this direction, but I rejected the idea of using a for loop to sort data. It seems that was misleading me very much. I successfully sorted the dates this way, thank you! :)
p.s.: the & bitwise operator was a whole new level to bring into my vocabulary +1 for that

Answer (score 1):

A working (but maybe a little quick and dirty) method:

Use the `.shift(-1)` method on the timestamp column of `programs_start_time` dataframe, to get an additional column with a name `date_end` indicating the timestamp of end for each TV program.

Then for each `example_timestamp` in the log file, you can query the TV programs dataframe like this: `df[(df['date_start']=<example_timestamp) & (df['date_end']>example_timestamp)]` (make sure you substitute df with your dataframe's name: `programs_start_time`) which will give you exactly one dataframe row and extract from it the name of the TV programm.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I have experimented with it a little, but I have found Zaraki Kenpachis's solution way more pythonic. :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution with histogram, using `numpy`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_p = pd.DataFrame([
        {
            "title": "\"Amiről a kövek mesélnek\"",
            "startTime_dt": "2019-05-29T00:00:40Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "Koffer - Kedvcsináló Kul(t)túrák Külföldön",
            "startTime_dt": "2019-05-29T00:22:44Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "Gubancok",
            "startTime_dt": "2019-05-29T00:48:08Z"
        }
    ])

df_v = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        "logid": 191605,
        "time": "2019-05-29 0:00:17"
    },
    {
        "logid": 191607,
        "time": "2019-05-29 0:00:26"
    },
    {
        "logid": 191611,
        "time": "2019-05-29 0:01:20"
    }
])

df_p.startTime_dt = pd.to_datetime(df_p.startTime_dt)
df_v.time = pd.to_datetime(df_v.time)

# here's part where I convert datetime to timestamp in seconds - astype(int) casts it to nanoseconds, hence there's // 10**9
programmes_start = df_p.startTime_dt.astype(int).values // 10**9
viewings_starts = df_v.time.astype(int).values // 10**9

# make bins for histogram
# add zero to the beginning of the array
# add value that is time an hour after the start of the last given programme to the end of the array
programmes_start = np.pad(programmes_start, (1, 1), mode='constant', constant_values=(0, programmes_start.max()+3600))

histogram = np.histogram(viewings_starts, bins=programmes_start)
print(histogram[0]
# prints [2 1 0 0]
```

Interpretation: there were 2 log entries before 'Amiről a kövek mesélnek' started, 1 log entry between starts of 'Amiről a kövek mesélnek' and 'Koffer - Kedvcsináló Kul(t)túrák Külföldön', 0 log entries between starts of 'Koffer - Kedvcsináló Kul(t)túrák Külföldön' and 'Gubancok' and 0 entries after start od 'Gubancok'. Which, looking at the data you provided, seems correct :) Hope this helps.

NOTE: I assume, that you have the date of the viewings. You don't have them in the example log file, but they appear in the screenshot - so I assumed that you can compute/get them somehow and added them by hand to the input dict.

Comment: Thanks, I have used a snippet of the histogram part of the code and tinkered with it a little when I was plotting the data. :)